# Why $u(x+ \Delta x)\cdot v(x+ \Delta x)=(u+\Delta u)(v+\Delta v)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I'm reading Hairer/Wanner's: *Analysis by Its history*.

> [image]

It's not clear what he's doing here $(p.84)$:

Why did he rewrite $u(x+ \Delta x)$ as $(u+\Delta u)$? It seems he's trying to say that it's possible to write the function as a sum of the function and the increment, but not all functions behave as $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. Why is it legitimate in this case? Is it because $\Delta u$ is a "*very small number*" and then the difference doesn't matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He is not saying $u(x+\Delta x)=u(x)+u(\Delta x)$.

Rather, he is using the definition of $\Delta u$: $$\Delta u = u(x+\Delta x)-u(x).$$ So $u+\Delta u=u(x+\Delta x)$ and similarly $v+\Delta v=v(x+\Delta x)$.

It's important to realize that $\Delta u$ depends both on $x$ and $\Delta x$.

So if $x$ is a measurement of time, then $\Delta u$ is the change of $u$ in the time period of length $\Delta x$ starting at $x$.

Comment: Oh, I'd ask another stupid question. But I noticed (with your help) that the trick is to write $\Delta u=u(x+\Delta x)-u(x)$ as $u(x+\Delta x)=u(x)+\Delta x$ and then make the appropriate substitutions.

Comment: It wasn't a stupid question. The use of $\Delta$ can be tricky notation - it's not a value, itself, which can be confusing.

Comment: I did the following:

$$\Delta y=(f(x)+\Delta y)(g(x)+\Delta y)-f(x)g(x) \\ \Delta y=f(x)g(x)+f(x)\Delta y +g(x)\Delta y + \Delta y^2-f(x)g(x) \\ \Delta y=f(x)\Delta y + g(x)\Delta y+\Delta y^2 \\ \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=f(x) \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} + g(x)\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}+\frac{\Delta y^2}{\Delta x}$$

What happens with the last term? I assume it vanishes, isn't it?

Comment: (An additional point: In the book, the authors use $d$ and $\Delta$ for seemingly similar meanings. Are there any differences between them?)

Comment: No, $\Delta y = f(x+\Delta x)g(x+\Delta x) - f(x)g(x)$. There should not be any $\Delta y$ on the right hand side. @Voyska Then write $f(x+\Delta x)=f(x)+\Delta f$ and similarly for $g$.

Comment: As for the $d$ in your book, it is hard to say, but $dx$ is usually a virtual difference, kind of representing an infinitesimal value. It is often kind of a pure notation, not actually representing a value. $\Delta x$ is always an actual real number - we just let $\Delta x$ approach zero, but at any time, we are computing with $\Delta x$ a real number. $dx$ a notation indicating that process of sending $\Delta x\to 0$.

Comment: But then, the meaning of $\Delta f$ will be the same as the meaning of $\Delta y$?

Comment: No, $\Delta f = f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)$ and $\Delta y=y(x+\Delta x)-y(x)$. Those are not the same thing. @Voyska

Comment: Corrected. I reached the following:

$$dy=f(x)dg+g(x)df+df \cdot dg$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x)\frac{dg}{dx}+g(x)\frac{df}{dx}+\frac{df \cdot dg}{dx}$$

I assume that the last term vanishes, just as the book says.

Comment: Technically, you can't just start using $df,dg,dx$ - you need to use $\Delta$ for a while to get an expression for $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$, then let $\Delta x\to 0$ to get that $\frac{\Delta f\cdot \Delta g}{dx}\to 0$ and the rest approaches $f(x)\frac{dg}{dx} + g(x)\frac{df}{dx}$. But typing $\Delta$ can get tiresome, so the above is okay for here.